# Cascode Amplifier vs Cascode Amplifier with CMOS current source

Tags: mosfet, current, amplifier, cmos

So I studied the gain cascode amplifier as follows,
[image]

I understand that the gain for this circuit is approximately -(gmro)^2

Now, here is a different circuit using the cascode amplifier but instead of a standard current source, we use a PMOS current mirror.
[image]

Now, I am told that the gain for this circuit is just gmro, no square. Why is that? I mean clearly all we did was replace a standard current source with a PMOS current mirror? **Shouldn't the gain for this circuit also be -(gmro)^2?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's to do with the ro of the current mirror M4. Cascode amplifiers need very large load resistors to get the theoretical gain that you quote. With a MOS current mirror the output resistance drops to r0. The solution is to use a cascode current mirror.